Why is there a difference between the results using DirichletCondition and directly given boundary condition?
The  simulation code

(*The code*) 
TH = 800; TL = 300; U = 1000; J = 1;
αp[x_] := 1.4831*10^-3 - 1.3905*10^-5 T[x] + 
          5.3964*10^-8 (T[x])^2 - 8.8088*10^-11*(T[x])^3 + 5.0618*10^-14 (T[x])^4;
κp[x_] := 1.157451*10^-1 + 4.474949*10^-2 (T[x]) - 
          2.597266*10^-4 (T[x])^2 + 5.558334*10^-7*(T[x])^3 - 3.676412*10^-10 (T[x])^4;
ρp[x_] := 2.728214*10^-5 - 2.254395*10^-7 (T[x]) + 
          7.275808*10^-10 (T[x])^2-6.25084*10^-13*(T[x])^3;
G1 = NDSolve[{D[κp[x]*D[T[x], x], x] + ρp[x]*J^2 -T[x]*D[αp[x], x]*J == 0,
              DirichletCondition[T[x] == TH, x == 0],  
              DirichletCondition[T[x] == TL, x == 0.01]}, T[x], {x, 0, 0.01}];
Plot[(T[x] /. G1), {x, 0, 0.01}]
G2 = NDSolve[{D[κp[x]*D[T[x], x], x] + ρp[x]*J^2 -T[x]*D[αp[x], x]*J == 0,
              T[0] == TH, T[0.01] == TL}, T[x], {x}]
Plot[(T[x] /. G2), {x, 0, 0.01}]


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you very much. A picture containing the code has been uploaded.

Thank you for your help. The uploaded code can run. But the graphs of the two numerical simulations are very different. Can you help check it.

TH and TL  and the other parameters are added.

This is an issue of using FINITE ELEMENTS with how you set up the DirichletCondition. I am still trying to find out why. But this below shows that.
When setting up IC using DirichletCondition then FEM method is automatically used otherwise it is not used (may be finite difference or other methods are used then).
In your second case, FEM is not used since you did not use DirichletCondition.
This is the difference.
To see this, we can force the second case to use FEM, and now same output results. This is your first case.
TH=800;TL=300;U=1000;J=1;
αp[x_]:=1.4831*10^-3-1.3905*10^-5 T[x]+5.3964*10^-8 (T[x])^2-8.8088*10^-11*(T[x])^3+5.0618*10^-14 (T[x])^4;
κp[x_]:=1.157451*10^-1+4.474949*10^-2 (T[x])-2.597266*10^-4 (T[x])^2+5.558334*10^-7*(T[x])^3-3.676412*10^-10 (T[x])^4;
ρp[x_]:=2.728214*10^-5-2.254395*10^-7 (T[x])+7.275808*10^-10 (T[x])^2-6.25084*10^-13*(T[x])^3;

ic={DirichletCondition[T[x]==TH,x==0],DirichletCondition[T[x]==TL,x==0.01]}
ode=D[κp[x]*D[T[x],x],x]+ρp[x]*J^2-T[x]*D[αp[x],x]*J==0

G1=NDSolve[{ode,ic},T[x],{x,0,0.01}]
Plot[(T[x] /. G1), {x, 0, 0.01}]


Now lets try the second case
ic={T[0]==TH,T[0.01]==TL}
G2=NDSolve[{ode,ic},T[x],{x,0,0.01}] 
Plot[(T[x]/. G2),{x,0,0.01}]


To get same output as first case, we now force it to use FEM even though no DirichletCondition is used.
ic={T[0]==TH,T[0.01]==TL}
G2 = NDSolve[{ode, ic}, T[x], {x, 0, 0.01}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}] 
Plot[(T[x] /. G2), {x, 0, 0.01}]


We see now we get same result. Using DirichletCondition or not. Since in both cases FEM was used.
Now the question is why the result is different when using FEM vs. not. Will try to find out. I am no expert in NDSolve. But if I find out will update unless someone else can figure it out. I just wanted to point out the difference is due to the underlying method used and not how you set the BC per say.
Update
Found the option you need to obtain same result. If you use "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1 or 0.01 then you get similar result from from first case as second.
ic = {DirichletCondition[T[x] == TH, x == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[T[x] == TL, x == 0.01]}
ode = D[κp[x]*D[T[x], x], x] + ρp[x]*J^2 - 
   T[x]*D[αp[x], x]*J == 0
G1 = NDSolve[{ode, ic}, T[x], {x, 0, 0.01}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}}];
Plot[(T[x] /. G1), {x, 0, 0.01}]


The curve does not exactly match, but this shows that some option(s) needs tweeking when using FEM.
But using "MaxCellMeasure"->0.001 gives back the original plot! So it looks like 0.001 is default.
So I think it is due to how the mesh is automatically generated.
Hopefully someone who knows more about FEM can shed more light on this.

Thank you a lot!

This explains when the FEM is used and when not.

Actually, the default is "MaxCellMeasure"->0.0005,at least for this problem, as can be verified using Flatten[G1[[1, 1, 2]] /. x -> "Grid"] // Length.  FEM cannot solve this nonlinear problem with only 40 cells. In contrast, the finite difference solution uses 146 cells.

For nonlinear ODEs, like this one, the FEM method uses FindRoot to solve a large set of nonlinear algebraic equations, in this case 40 equations.  Sometimes, FindRoot finds the wrong solution, or none at all.  In such cases, providing an initial guess can be helpful:
G3 = NDSolve[{ode, ic}, T[x], {x, 0, 0.01}, 
   InitialSeeding -> T[x] == TH + x (TL - TH)/.01];
Plot[(T[x] /. G3), {x, 0, 0.01}, PlotRange -> All]


Why Mathematica does not use as a default the simple initial guess of a straight line from the beginning to end point is unclear to me.
Addendum: Even InitialSeeding -> T[x] == (TH + TL)/2 gives the correct result.

It uses 0 by default, where would the initial guess of a straight line come from? And even if we had that information, then there will be other eqns where that particular guess would not work.

@user21 I had been thinking of a boundary-value problem, where the initial guess could be a straight line connecting the two end points.  For an initial-value problem, a constant value equal to the initial value would seem better than a constant value of zero.
